# Role-based authorization with controller inheritance

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I'm working with ASP.NET Core 2.1

I have an abstract base class for my controllers, that has a basic implementation for CRUD operations. We are looking to restrict most of these to be only callable for some users (let's say those having the Admin role), but allow some to everybody or another role.

Would it work somehow like this?

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
abstract class BaseController<T> : Controller
{
    public virtual IActionResult GetAll() { }
    public virtual IActionResult Create(T entity) { }
    public virtual IActionResult Read(int id) { }
    public virtual IActionResult Delete(int key) { }
}

[Authorize(Roles = "ClassRole")]
class EntityController : BaseController<Entity>
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public override IActionResult GetAll() { } //callable by anyone?

    //Create not overriden so callable only by Admins (and/or ClassRole?)

    public override IActionResult Read() //overridden but no attribute so ClassRole?

    [Authorize(Roles = "MehodRole")]
    public override IActionResult Delete() { } //all 3 (Admin, ClassRole, MethodRole) or something?
}
```

It gets only crazier if there are other Authorize attributes in the base class as well, and multiple roles in one attribute, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Multiple `Authorize` attributes logically AND together. In other words, if you define `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` and `[Authorize(Roles = "ClassRole")]`. then in order for a user to access the controller/action they must be in *both* the "Admin" and "ClassRole" roles. Unfortunately, there is no workaround for this. If you need to override/change things on your derived controllers, your best bet is to switch to using policies instead. Then, inside your policy handler you can make more granular decisions about which role is required based on the route.